# How do I return certain information from a request?

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm new to node.js, and I'm creating my first discord bot out of boredom. I've figured everything else out on my own, but I can't figure out how to log only certain parts of the information I receive. I'm using an api called Jikanjs. It's an unofficial PHP/REST API for MyAnimeList. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
else if (command === 'animeinfo') {
        jikanjs.search('anime', String(args[0]), 1, {limit: 1})
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        })
    }
```

Here are the results I get from using the code:

[image]

It returns a ton of information, but I only want to see/use four of those. The mal_id, title, episodes, and synopsis. Any idea on how I would go about doing that?

Comment: Check [this guide](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27). It basically explains you how to log everything in Chrome instead of the normal command line, so you can do the usual minifaction/expansion and all. Neat!

Answer (score 2):

You would probably want to use the javascript `map` function to process the data. map is a function that you will use very frequently in javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
else if (command === 'animeinfo') {
  jikanjs.search('anime', String(args[0]), 1, { limit: 1 })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response)
      const myProcessedData = response.results.map(function(result) {
        return {
          mal_id: result.mal_id,
          title: result.title,
          episodes: result.episodes,
          synopsis: result.synopsis
        }
      });
      // now myProcessedData is an array of objects containing those 4 fields
    })
}
```